# Can't WRITE out a text when running Python Shell

Tags: raspbian, python

Sorry to disturb you guys again, I have successfully created a blinking led.

But the problem I'm facing right now is I wanted to create a WRITE method to record all the details that shown on Python Shell.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'
import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT

##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(numTimes,speed):
    for i in range(0,numTimes): ## Run loop numTimes
        print "Iteration " + str(i+1) ## Print current loop
        GPIO.output(7,True) ## Switch on pin 7
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
        GPIO.output(7,False) ## Switch off pin 7
        time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
    print "Done" ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
    GPIO.cleanup()

## Ask user for total number of blinks and length of each blink
iterations = raw_input("Enter total number of times to blink: ")
speed = raw_input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")

## Start Blink() function. Convert user input from strings to numeric data types
Blink(int(iterations),float(speed))

While True:

    #Open Log File
    f=open('leddata.txt','a')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:$M")
    outvalue = Blink()
    outstring = str(timestamp)+ " " + str(outvalue) + "\n"
    print outstring
    f.write(outstring)
    f.close()
```

I get quite a number of errors and very lost now.

Hope you guys could help me out with it, as soon as possible, thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may want Blink() to be a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

In that case you need to `yield` something to `outvalue`.

You'll need to can create the generator like this

```
blink = Blink(int(iterations...)
```

Then call `next(blink)` to step through the iterations.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)  ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT

def Blink(numTimes, speed):
    for i in range(numTimes):
        print "Iteration " + str(i+1)   ## Print current loop
        GPIO.output(7, True)            ## Switch on pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)               ## Wait
        GPIO.output(7, False)           ## Switch off pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)               ## Wait
        yield "something for outvalue"
    print "Done"
    GPIO.cleanup()

## Ask user for total number of blinks and length of each blink
iterations = raw_input("Enter total number of times to blink: ")
speed = raw_input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")

## Start Blink() generator. Convert user input from strings to numeric data types
blink = Blink(int(iterations), float(speed))

## Open Log File
with open('leddata.txt', 'a') as f:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:$M")
    for outvalue in blink:
        outstring = "{} {}\n".format(timestamp, outvalue)
        print outstring
        f.write(outstring)
```

Comment: Ok, I will pass the code here, John La Rooy.

Comment: I've changed the end of your program a little, since the `While True:` doesn't really make sense. You'd end up crashing with a `StopIteration` exception

Comment: John La Rooy, I gotta another error after copying your code. This is the error statement: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Blinking LED with WRITE.py", line 30, in <module> for outvalue in blink: NameError: name 'blink' is not defined

Comment: You didn't copy the line that defines it.

Comment: Can work already, John La Rooy. Thanks alot, John La Rooy.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call `Blink()`, you pass it two arguments, as you should. However, when you call it inside the `while` loop, you don't pass it any arguments, which is why the program crashes.

Learn to read the error messages; all that red seems scary at first, but contained within it is much of the information you need to debug your program.